Need Clang version at least 16
I am tried to compile the Apache Doris on macOS 13.3.1 follow by this document: https://doris.apache.org/docs/install/source-install/compilation-mac/. When I run the bash build.sh command, shows error like this:
Compiling as RELEASE
-- old Boost_INCLUDE_DIR    : /Users/xiaoqiangjiang/source/third-party/doris/thirdparty/installed/include
-- Found Boost: /Users/xiaoqiangjiang/source/third-party/doris/thirdparty/installed/lib64/cmake/Boost-1.81.0/BoostConfig.cmake (found version "1.81.0")
Boost found
-- Boost_INCLUDE_DIR    : /Users/xiaoqiangjiang/source/third-party/doris/thirdparty/installed/include
-- Looking for MapViewOfFile
-- Looking for MapViewOfFile(0,0,0,0,0) - not found
-- Looking for _close
-- Looking for _close((int)0) - not found
-- Looking for _read
-- Looking for _read((int)0, (void*)0, (unsigned int)0) - not found
-- Looking for _open
-- Looking for _open(0,0,0) - not found
-- Looking for _write
-- Looking for _write((int)0, (const void*)0, (unsigned int)0) - not found
-- Looking for _unlink
-- Looking for _unlink((const char*)0) - not found
-- Looking for _ftime
-- Looking for _ftime(0) - not found
-- Looking for _mkdir
-- Looking for _mkdir((const char*)0) - not found
-- Checking support new float byte<->float conversions
-- Checking support new float byte<->float conversions - yes
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:268 (message):
  Need Clang version at least 16


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!

I have tried to upgrade the clang version to 16 and this is the current clang version with my macOS system:
> clang --version
clang version 16.0.6
Target: arm64-apple-darwin22.4.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /opt/local/libexec/llvm-16/bin

Am I misssing something? what should I do to fixed this issue? I also tried to use the brew version:
> clang --version
Homebrew clang version 18.1.7
Target: arm64-apple-darwin22.4.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /opt/homebrew/opt/llvm/bin

maybe the app still using the old version /usr/bin/clang.

You have two clang environments, pick the old environment and delete it, then point all software to the correct environment
